# SQL query to get specific row based on of value

Tags: sql

Given this table:

```
SubstationNo SubstationType
----------------------------
     1411             1566
     1411             135
     1422             1411
     1433             1433
```

how to get distinct values from two different columns as values separated by the `|` symbol in one row

Result needed is

```
1411|1422|1433|1566|135|1433
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: I guess that is multiple result records not just one with all values concatenated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` function concats all rows as a single string. The query here will give all unique values from both columns

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(
    select distinct * from (SELECT column1
    FROM tablename
    UNION
    SELECT column2
    FROM tablename) SEPARATOR '|') AS rowValue
FROM  tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do a subselect with a union to *mix* the columns. Not sure if available on your RDBMS.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(
  SELECT SubstationNo FROM table
  UNION
  SELECT SubstationType FROM table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using `SQL Server`, then you can do this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT SubstationNo AS COL FROM Table1
  UNION
  SELECT SubstationType AS COL FROM Table1
)


SELECT DISTINCT 
STUFF((
     SELECT '|'+ CAST(COL AS VARCHAR(50)) 
     FROM CTE
     FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
FROM TABLE1
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/110a9/18)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you can use GROUP_CONCAT(), but in an easier way than Ajo Koshy's.

One GROUP_CONCAT for every column and then put them together via CONCAT()

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column1 SEPARATOR '|'), '|', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column2 SEPARATOR '|'))
FROM yourTable
```

Here's the [manual entry for GROUP_CONCAT().](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying this stuff in `SQL SERVER` then try like below.. it will help you..

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
STUFF((
     SELECT '|'+ CAST(SubStation AS VARCHAR(50))
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SubstationNo SubStation
 FROM TableName
 UNION
 SELECT DISTINCT SubstationType as SubStation
 FROM TableName) res
     FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') as SubStation
FROM TableName
```